# loop to extract each array in array of arrays python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array of arrays

```
a = np.array([[11, 12, 13, 14],
           [15, 16, 17, 18],
           [19, 20, 21, 22]])
```

I want to make a loop to extract each row so final result would be

```
a(1) = [11, 12, 13, 14]
a(2) = [15, 16, 17, 18]
a(3) = [19, 20, 21, 22]
```

then reshape each a(i) into 2x2 fortran array

```
a(1) = np.array([[11, 13],
                 [12, 14])
a(2) = np.array([[15, 17],
                 [16, 18])
a(3) = np.array([[19, 21],
                 [20, 22])
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using list comprehension. Please note that `a(1)`  is not the way to access elements in python. Also, the index starts from `0`. You can now print `a[0]`, `a[1]` and so on.

```
a=[i.reshape((2,2)).T for i in a] # Update after your comment
```

**Output**

```
[array([[11, 13],
    [12, 14]]), array([[15, 17],
    [16, 18]]), array([[19, 21],
    [20, 22]])]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, is there anyway to create a loop that separates each row and store them in that manner? 
as a[0], a[1],...., a[i] since I have +600 record

Comment: My answer exactly does what you are saying. It is storing as `a[0]`, `a[1]` and so on. You can think of it as `a` being the big shelf and `[0]`, `[1]` and so on  being the drawers of that shelf.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I mean in an individual arrays, so a[0], a[1], and a[2] each are an individual array

Comment: Again confusing. In my answer above, `a[0]` is an individual array. What you are saying doesn't make sense to me because `a[0]` `a[1]` etc all can be individual arrays **BUT** they still belong to an array or list which is `a`.

Comment: My bad, you're right. How can I solve the "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'T'" error when using reshape((2, 2).T? I want the resultant array to be sorted in fortran manner. so output to be [array([[11, 13],
    [12, 14]]), array([[15, 17],
    [16, 18]]), array([[19, 21],
    [20, 22]])]

Comment: Check my edited answer and the output. It now computes transposes as you want.

Answer (score 1):

#### you can directly iterate it using for loop.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[11, 12, 13, 14],
           [15, 16, 17, 18],
           [19, 20, 21, 22]])

b = list()
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    b.append(a[i].reshape(2,2))
for itr in b:
    print(b[i])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, is there anyway to create a loop that separates each row and store them in that manner? 
as a[0], a[1],...., a[i] since I have +600 record

Comment: I updated my answer it will help you and now you can perform on list b.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
In [4]: a
Out[4]: 
array([[11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18],
       [19, 20, 21, 22]])

In [5]: a[0]
Out[5]: array([11, 12, 13, 14])

In [6]: a[1]
Out[6]: array([15, 16, 17, 18])

In [7]: a[2]
Out[7]: array([19, 20, 21, 22])

In [9]: a[0].reshape(2,2).T
Out[9]: 
array([[11, 13],
       [12, 14]])

In [13]: for i in a:
    ...:     print(i.reshape(2,2).T)
    ...:     
    ...:     
[[11 13]
 [12 14]]
[[15 17]
 [16 18]]
[[19 21]
 [20 22]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast respond, 
I have a set of +600 array, is there any way to make a loop that separate each row/array into a[i] instead of defining each one?

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

```
for ele in a:
    print(ele.reshape(2,2))
```

Or you can use:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[i].reshape(2,2))
```

Also, in the above please remember that, a(i) is invalid. You need to write a[i].

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, is there anyway to create a loop that separates each row and store them in that manner? 
as a[0], a[1],...., a[i] since I have +600 record

Comment: Is there any certain number of indexes that you want to use? Can you please specify how yyou want to use them? Maybe then I could help...

Answer (score 0):

One can use *zip* with a shift for each list.
*map* is needed to turn the zipped tuples into lists.

```
>>>[list(map(list,zip(l,l[2:]))) for l in a]   

[[[11, 13], [12, 14]], [[15, 17], [16, 18]], [[19, 21], [20, 22]]]
```